# Why some website are not availables in Google Ads Display Network?

Tags: advertising, google-ads

I'd like to have my dynamic ads running on some website where i see these are displaying Google Ads, but when i go to edit the targeting preferences (display ads) to add them, i cannot find these websites, while digiting their domain, or URL or name.
Is there something i'm missing?